# What is the exactly Perf buffer size?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, cpu, perf

after I read the [manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/perf_event_open.2.html) of `perf_event_open()`, I have a few question about buffer's size in capture sampling event.

In the description section, it says that

> A sampling event periodically writes measurements to a
>          buffer that can then be accessed via mmap(2).

And when the buffer overflow, PMU will trigger the PMI, we can access the content of buffer via `mmap()` system call. (is my understanding correct?)

But the question is, how big is the Perf buffer? Can I set a new value (buffer length) to overwrite it?

Variable `__u64 data_size` in the `struct perf_event_mmap_page` only indicates the records size in this time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your understanding is correct, when you say that you can use `mmap` to collect perf data periodically.

Before I begin, `perf` uses two buffers to record different kinds of events. **An auxiliary buffer is used, under the main ring buffer( the ring buffer contains this auxiliary buffer ), to store different kinds of event information**. Since you are asking me about the main perf buffer I will try answering that.

You can modify the `perf` buffer size. As per the documentation, the `perf` buffer size is defined in terms of **pages**. It is defined to be **1 + 2^n** pages, where one page is required to store metadata about the ring buffer that `perf`  uses.

When you try recording events, using `perf record` , (read the manpage for perf record), you will have a switch `-m` which will allow you to specify the number of pages that will increase/decrease the **perf ring buffer**. The number of (mmap) pages that you specify must be a power of **2**.(However, you can also directly specify the size) Increasing the number of pages by 1, will increase the ring buffer size by **4kB** (which is the page-size, specified in code by 1 << 12).

However, as far as I know, this number of pages will only go so far as **2^31**. Moreover, using such a huge buffer will risk not recording any events at all or recording arbitrary events.

Comment: Thanks for your answering, I got it. :)